# XCode - Enabling push notifications requires already added Apple ID

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Trying to enable push notifications for my iOS app, it pops up this dialog:

[image: dialog]

I have already added one Apple ID, I have even tried adding two, but the dialog still pops up. I searched the web for an answer, I got referred to [this webpage](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate), but apparently it does not exist anymore.

Am I doing something wrong? I am new to XCode development.

Comment: Do you have an active Developer account?

Comment: Yes, I can log in to [developer console](http://developer.apple.com)

Comment: did you added push notification certificate in developer account and installed it locally ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable Push Notifications of your app, apple require developer as below:

1. Become apple developer membership
2. Enable Push Notification from sections "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles >> Identifiers >> Your App" in Apple Developer page.

Comment: can you give a valid link?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/
Make sure you enroll Apple Developer Membership so that can access it.

Comment: so I need to pay $100 per year only to be able to enable push notifications?

Comment: "only to be able". What do you mean?
$100 to become an Apple Dev. You can publish your app and do everything you want as Apple Developer.

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked the first question. An active develop account means a paid developer account.